# What is the grammatical function of “that” in “that which works”?

Tags: sentence-structure, functions

> There is no one road to success. Each one must find that which works.

What is this "that"?

Answer (score 2):

*That which* is a literary equivalent to *the one which*: not many people use it in speech.

So *that* is a pronoun (equivalent to *the one* or *the thing*), antecedent to the relative pronoun *which*.

Comment: so this "that" is a substitute for "road"

Comment: Sort of, but only pragmatically, not grammatically. _That which_ does not need an antecedent. Nietzche's famous aphorism _Was mich nicht umbringt, macht mich stärker._ is sometimes translated into English as _That which does not kikll me makes me stronger_.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means "that one", "that specific road".

"Each one (that is, each person) must find that (specific road) which works."

Sorry this is a short post, it's all I can find to say about it.